# Why does python output negative hexadecimal?

Tags: python

http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html

The table says unsigned hexadecimal, my outputs are signed...

```
for a in words: # list of word
    print '%x'%hash(a)
```

also http://codepad.org/Cvd0Bg2T

Comment: You should also show your outputs

Comment: So you want us to guess at which part of your code is wrong without actually seeing it?

Comment: edited ! sorry, I'm doing hash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That documentation is for Python 2.4. You're probably using a more recent version. Take a look at a [newer](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) version of that table - `%x` is signed now.

Answer (score 2):

The change appeared (or seemed to) in 2.6; in http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html, U find:
...
x   Unsigned hexadecimal (lowercase).
in http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting:
...
'x'     Signed hexadecimal (lowercase).

Not a word about the change in 2.6 "whats new"

The new policy parts from the "printf" policy.
while debuging C code, I used to have an ipython interpreter open, next to my gdb terminal, for address calculation. This doesnt work any more, and I find no easy turnaround.